# Are there any guide with commonly used settings on sound synthesis?

Tags: sound, synthesizer, synthesis

I just saw the new york sound synthesis course on youtube.
It's pretty good, but I wonder if there are any guide or pdf with the most common used settings in music, like a string pad on trance music or getting a certain instrument sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's the rightfully famous Synth Secrets series by Sound on Sound magazine:
http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/allsynthsecrets.htm

And the classic Synthesizer Cookbook:
[http://www.amazon.com/Welshs-Synthesizer-Cookbook-Programming-Universal/dp/B000ERHA4S](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ERHA4S)

Comment: SOS is a good one

Answer (score -1):

It depends on you maths and computer programming level. Sound synthesis is very much related to sound analysis which requires Fourier transforms and many other mathematical backgrounds.

Once you studied discrete Fourier transform, filtering  and computer programming, you understand how VST and programs like 'Live' or 'Reason' are made.

Comment: my answer is very good because I applied precisely that to myself, and I needed 8 years to study the maths and the computer programming theory associated to sound synthesis/analysis and computer-assisted music. what's your problem with that ?